# Android Menu Options checkboxes unchecked on orientation change fix

Tags: android, orientation, android-checkbox

In my app, when options are checked in the overflow menu, then the orientation is changed, they become unchecked. Any way to fix this?
I know `onSavedInstance` should be able to help me here, but I don't know how to implement it in my case.

Here's an Example of how my overflow checkboxes are handled in the main activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {


switch (item.getItemId()) {

case R.id.subtract_option:
    if (item.isChecked()){
        item.setChecked(false);
        subtractMode = false;

    } else{
        item.setChecked(true);
        subtractMode = true;
    }

    return true;

default:
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
```

So how would I implement the `onSavedInstanceState` in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556758/handle-orientation-from-portrait-to-landscape-mode-for-checkbox

Comment: Are You doing any configuration change handling in Your app? Code of that 'overflow' menu might be also useful.

Comment: You should save your checkbox states in onSavedInstanceState()...

Comment: No, i didn't gna try what's below. I reposted because my post dried out and i didnt get a specific answer, so i posted this with specific code, and flagged my past one for deletion...

Comment: @Axtn95 I merged the two questions. However, you should not repeat your question. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers to learn what to do when you don't get answers.

Comment: use onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915952/how-to-save-state-during-orientation-change-in-android-if-the-state-is-made-of-m

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how Android handles orientation changes.  It actually kills your activity and restarts it.  There's two ways to fix it.

1)Implement onSaveInstanceState, write all your state to an object (including the values of checkboxes) and implement onRestoreInstanceState to reverse the process.

2)Add android:configChanges="orientation".  This will stop the overriding behavior.  It will also break the automatic reloading of layouts if you have separate landscape andd portrait layouts.

I recommend route 2 if your don't have separate layouts for the orientations.  If you do and your app is simple, I suggest route 1.  If you need that and your app is complex you're screwed and in for a world of pain.

Comment: Would you mind helping me a bit more if i posted some code? I definitely have to implement onSaveInstanceState, but my brain can't process how to implement it in my case!

Answer (score 1):

override onSaveInstanceState method.

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState( outState );
        outState.putInt( "position", this.position );

    }
```

and on onCreateView

```
if ( savedInstanceState != null )
{
            int temp;
            temp = savedInstanceState.getInt( "position", -1 );
            Log.i( LOG_TAG, "temp....." + temp );
           // do whatever you want
}
```

Make appropriate changes as per your need.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? Im a noob, so i needed help to actually implement with my code. What would i put in onsaveinstancestate?

Comment: you can save the last state of your checkbox. let say it has checked than put 1 and if not than put 0 . now in savedInstanceState.getInt( "position", -1 ); you will get the value according to that you will set the value to your checkbox again

Comment: How do i reference the checkbox state? I check and uncheck options using the Item tag in the onMenuItemSelected, how would i do something similar in the onSaveInstanceState? Please bear with me lol

Answer (score 0):

Visit [How to save state during orientation change in Android if the state is made of my classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915952/how-to-save-state-during-orientation-change-in-android-if-the-state-is-made-of-m)

he says to use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method to save your data on orientation changes.